# Limit of continuous sequence of functions with respect to $L^{2}$ norm is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be continuous functions on $[0,1]$ which converge to a measurable function $f$ in the following sense: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} |f_{n}(x) - f(x)|^{2} dx \to 0$$

Show $f$ is continuous.

I'm still new at this, but my understanding is that the hypothesis is that the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to the $L^{2}$ norm. This should imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = f(x)$ (but I think I might need to make use of some theorem to justify the limit and the integral commuting?) From there, I believe you can justify that this convergence is actually uniform (almost everywhere) by Egorov's theorem?

I'm probably a bit off, my I would appreciate if someone could correct my misunderstandings.

Comment: $f$ need not be continuous. The assertion is wrong.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard counterexample goes along the lines of

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\qquad 0 &, x < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\
2^n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) &, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\
\qquad 1 &, x > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.  \end{cases}$$

The $L^2$-limit of that sequence is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 &, x < \frac{1}{2}\\ 1 &, x \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$$

(or any function almost everywhere equal to that), which has no continuous representative.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $f_n$ to be bumps around $x=1/2$ that are basically $0$ everywhere and then go up to $1$ in a small interval around $1/2$, where the widths of the intervals goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then your sequence of functions will converge in norm to the function which is $0$ everywhere except $1/2$ and $1$ at $1/2$. The sequence of functions will even converge pointwise to this limit. So maybe you mean to say, there EXISTS a continuous function which satisfies the limit of norms requirement, assuming that the sequence of functions converges? Even then, I'm not sure if it's true.