# Is the set of non-decreasing bounded continuous functions a compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

$\Phi$ is the set of functions $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is bounded, non-decreasing
and continuous on $[a, b]$. Is $\Phi$ compact with $L^2$ norm?

What about
$\Psi$ is the set of functions $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is non-decreasing
and continuous on $[a, b]$. Is $\Psi$ compact?

Comment: Compact with respect to which topology?

Comment: Any monotone function in $[a,b]$ is also bounded in $[a,b]$, therefore $\Phi = \Psi$.

Comment: Any continuous function on $[a,b]$ is also bounded, therefore $\Phi=\Psi$

Comment: What metric?  ${}$

Comment: I reedited the question.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\qquad 0 &, x < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\
2^n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) &, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\
\qquad 1 &, x > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.  \end{cases}$$

The $L^2$-limit of that sequence is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 &, x < \frac{1}{2}\\ 1 &, x \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$$

(Source above counterexample: [Limit of continuous sequence of functions with respect to $L^{2}$ norm is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763665/limit-of-continuous-sequence-of-functions-with-respect-to-l2-norm-is-contin)). Then $f_n$ is bounded, continuous and non-decreasing, yet its limit is not continuous. Hence, $\Phi$ is not $L_2$-closed and thus not compact.

Comment: Thanks. What about the norm $(,)=\sup|−| $.

Comment: That's another question and should be asked in another post.

Comment: Thanks. I recreate a question.